# is it possible to identify a unique range in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a vehicle reservation system. I am having issues where for some reason the reservations are over lapping. is there a way in mysql to mark a range as unique?

so if i have the following record in the database
vehicle_id = 10
begin = '2013-06-01 10:00:00'
end = '2013-06-10 10:00:00'

and if i tried to add a reservation for the same vehicle and with in that range I need to not allow that to happen and return a duplicate error or some type of error.

Is this possible is MySQL at all?

Thanks

Comment: I think triggers may help you, but I don't understand them well. You should do some research.

Comment: There's not declarative way to do that. You'll need to write some triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Just run an SQL query looking for the details you are about to enter i.e

```
select something from reservations where vehicle_id = 10 and begin ='dateFrom' and end = 'dateTo'
```

If this comes back with a record then don't allow a duplicate to be inserted.

If this isn't what you are after, please clarify your question.

Comment: This is what i have currently but there is something weird that is causing duplicates somewhere and i am not sure where. Si i am trying to prevent that from happening at the database level and not at the client level.

Comment: @Ben - Without more info in the OP, it's hard to say what IS right here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select vehicle_id from reservations where vehicle_id = 10 
       AND vehicle_id NOT IN (select vehicle_id from reservations WHERE '$yourDateTocheck' BETWEEN  `begin` and `end`)
```

Comment: this is the same idea as the previous answer. but i need to handle it at MySQL level because i am not sure what is causing this issue as i do have a query to check for existing record prior the insert but something not clear is happening.

Comment: but it is still the same idea "I will have to run a query prior inserting the data into the tables. the problem here is that i am not sure what is inserting the data in the tables. I need to know if MySQL can handle that so that way i can see error displaying on the script that is creating this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The classical reservation validation....
You must verify that you obtain these 3 Not:
The new reservation cannot begin inside, or end inside an existing reservation. Also the new reservation cannot cover ( start before and end after) any existing reservation.

The MySQL expression:

```
WHERE
'$asked_date_begin' NOT BETWEEN DB_RESERV_DATE_BEGIN AND DB_RESERV_DATE_END

AND

'$asked_date_end'   NOT BETWEEN DB_RESERV_DATE_BEGIN AND DB_RESERV_DATE_END

AND
  NOT ('$asked_date_begin' >= DB_RESERV_DATE_BEGIN AND '$asked_date_end' <= 
        DB_RESERV_DATE_END )
```

Comment: Last part (last NOT), comparison should be: <= and >= so that the asked (interval of date) would cover entirely an existing reservation, which would prevent a bad reservation.